# Update template text with user input

Tags: vba, outlook

I want my email template to prompt me for input, and replace specified fields with my input.

For example my email will be like:

> Hello [name]

I want a box to pop up where I can enter the name and have it appear throughout the email, replacing [name].

Answer (score 0):

Using my example, by saving "#0#" in your template in the "to:" section of the email, by clicking this template it will prompt you to change that entry with the "Email Address" question.

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call OpenTemplate

End Sub

Sub OpenTemplate()

    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("Template Location")

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Replace(.To, "#0#", InputBox("Email Address"))
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "#1#", InputBox("Prompt 1"))
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "#2#", InputBox("Prompt 2"))
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "#3#", InputBox("Prompt 3"))
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "#4#", InputBox("Prompt 4"))

        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```